# Where i have to use fragment transaction whether onstart() or OncreateView() method

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here i need to refresh the fragment from itself. So that i am going to using below code.

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Above code is should be used in onstart() method or Oncreate() method for refreshing the current fragment from itself

Comment: In `onStart()` method.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
From here you can under stand which method will call 1st and which after that,
So u can add this code where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `onStart()` You use the `onCreateView()` method in the fragment itself to define the xml layout that code will be using and the elements instantiated in that xml file.

On a more technical background, a fragment is always created in the `onStart()` method, hence taking precendence over the `onCreateView()` method. The reason is because in some cases, before displaying the fragment, the app needs to perform some background processes beforehand such as validation or getting data from the activity calling the fragment. This is done in the `onStart()` method before displaying the fragment.